# capistrano backup db before migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I know how to backup my db using capistrano scripts.

```
    before 'deploy:migration', 'db:backup'
```

However, backing up the database takes a long time and I really only want to do this when deployment includes a migration.  Otherwise, I rather do the deployment without the backup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?` to find out whether there is a migration pending or not. However, I think that you cannot put this check directly in a capistrano task.

I would create a **rake task** that would run the DB backup but only if there are pending migrations (i.e. if `needs_migration?` is `true`).

Then I would create a **capistrano task** that would simply call the rake task before the `deploy:migration` task during deployment.